# HipHop Fatal error: Class undefined: mysqli

Tags: php, nginx, hhvm

I'm using:

`HipHop VM v2.3.3 (rel)` (so HHVM-fastcgi)

When I use this: `$mysqli = new mysqli("...` I get:

`HipHop Fatal error: Class undefined: mysqli`

What can this mean?

PS:
Php -v = `PHP 5.4.24-1+sury.org~precise+1 (cli) (built: Jan 24 2014 11:05:09)`

Comment: check that you have the package `php5-mysql` installed

Comment: Googling "hhvm mysqli" shows you instantly that HHVM doesn't support mysqli. Please, do google before asking here..

Comment: This is true and false at the same time, I have mysqli working with HHVM, but after the upgrade to v2.3.3 it stopped, so it worked before :-S

Answer (score 1):

The `mysqli` extension is being worked on. It is expected to land in HHVM 2.5.0 as the 2.4.0 branch has already been cut.

https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Release-Schedule

Comment: Aha, so how can I use the `hhvm-nightly` exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Ok according to what I found, mysqli isn't implemented in hiohop, only the older mysql extention is though, you'll need to convert your db calls to use mysql not mysqli.

Also here's [an issue link on github](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/811)

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not using php5-fpm but, HHVM

Comment: well I don't really know what that is exactly, you just need to restart `php` after installing the extention

Comment: im trying to look around to find something useful